# open file fail(-1) with different flag settings

Tags: android, file-io, io, filesystems, embedded-linux

I have a question about using open() with different flags in Native android.

Because i want to open a file and ignore the cache& buffer, in oder to access the hardware(SD card) directly.
If the flag setting is 
`O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NDELAY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR| O_DIRECT | O_SYNC`
. I can got a positive file descriptor(fd).

But if I change the setting to
 `O_CREAT | O_RDWR | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR| O_DIRECT | O_SYNC`
the result is fail(-1).

Comment: File EXISTED. I remove the O_CREAT and it worked. But why the flags with O_NDELAY will not return fail?

Comment: #include <errno.h> and check the value of errno. If it is EAGAIN it just means you need to try again

Comment: Thanks, followed your advice and sawdust's answer. I can debug the error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the flag setting is O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_NDELAY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR| O_DIRECT | O_SYNC . I can got a positive file descriptor(fd).

That is not quite correct usage of the form

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

> But if I change the setting to O_CREAT | O_RDWR | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR| O_DIRECT | O_SYNC the result is fail(-1).

What you call *"setting"* is an invalid mixture of **flags** and **mode** symbols.  Also, since O_CREAT has been specified in **flags**, the **mode** argument must be supplied and it is not.
Try separating the **mode**s from the **flags**:

```
open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```