# Sharing memory with Android native app

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a shared memory region as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_test_Native_getShortBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
    jint channels, jint size)
{
    int bytes = (int)channels * (int)size * 2;
    int fd = open("/dev/ashmem", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd < 0) return errno;

    // 0 = let OS choose start address
    // last param = starting offset
    char *data = static_cast<char*>(mmap(NULL, bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
    if (data == MAP_FAILED) { close(fd); return errno; }

    return (jlong)data;
}
```

But I get err 22, EINVAL, which says that the `o_flags` are incorrect. I tried a variety of flags, such as `O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR`, but with no luck. The flags you see above came from someone who managed to pull this off ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165493/open-file-fail-1-with-different-flag-settings)).

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Without taking time to look into how you should do this, I'll point out that you are copying from an inapplicable example - you are not trying to open a regular file here, but a device node, so some of your settings are probably inapplicable.  You should either find an ashmem example, or look up the meaning of the individual settings (see for example section 2 linux manual page for open)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using my own file, like "/Test", but I always received invalid file error. Wasn't really sure what to put here on Android, and saw [someone else](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=4066) use "/dev/ashmem".

Comment: Well that wouldn't work for the entirely different reason that an app process isn't allowed to write in the root directory.  If you want to experiment with ordinary files, do so in your app's private storage directory, or the primary external storage if you have the relevant permission in your manifest.

Comment: Take a look at `ashmem_create_region()` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/lollipop-release/libcutils/ashmem-dev.c